# Reinforcement Learning partial derivative of loss function w.r.t. input of softmax

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, loss-functions, softmax

In the paper "Self-critical sequence training for image captioning" ([link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.00563.pdf)) on page 3 they define the loss function (of the parameters $\theta$) of an image captioning system as the negative expected reward of a generated sequence of words (Equation (3)):

$L(\theta) = - \mathbb{E}_{w^s \sim p_{\theta}}[r(w^s)]$ ,

Where $w^s = (w_1^s,..., w_T^s)$ and $w^s_t$ is the word sampled from the model at time step $t$.

The derivation of the gradient of $L(\theta)$ concludes with Equation (7), where the gradient of $L(\theta)$ is approximated with a single sample $w^s \sim p_\theta$:

$\triangledown_{\theta}L(\theta) \approx -(r(w^s) - b) \ \triangledown_{\theta}  log \ p_{\theta}(w^s)$,

Where $b$ is a reward baseline and $p_\theta(w^s)$ is the probability that sequence $w^s$ is sampled from the model. Up until here I understand what's going on. However, then they proceed with defining the partial derivative of $L(\theta)$ w.r.t. the input of the softmax function $s_t$ (final layer):

$\triangledown_{\theta}L(\theta) = \sum^T_{t=1} \frac{\partial L(\theta)}{\partial s_t} \frac{\partial s_t}{\partial \theta}$ $\quad$ (this I understand)

And (Equation (8)):

$\frac{\partial L(\theta)}{\partial s_t} \approx (r(w^s) - b) (p_\theta(w_t| h_t) - 1_{w^s_t})$,

Where $1_{w^s_t}$ is 0 everywhere but 1 at the $w^s_t$'th entry. How do you arrive at Equation (8)?

I'm happy to provide more information if necessary. In the paper "Sequence level training with recurrent neural networks" ([link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06732.pdf)) on page 7 they derive a similar result.

Comment: Answered here in the meantime: https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/10791/22545 .

Comment: Please refer this site to findyour answer:
https://medium.com/intro-to-artificial-intelligence/reinforce-a-policy-gradient-based-reinforcement-learning-algorithm-84bde440c816